# How can i add a collider to mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a mesh but not sure how to add a collider to it:
To GameObject it's easy to add but not sure how to add it to a mesh.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int resX = 2; // 2 minimum
    public int resZ = 2;
    public float length = 1f;
    public float width = 1f;

    private MeshFilter meshf;
    private UnityEngine.Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;

    private int v1;
    private int v2;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateMesh(); 
    }

    private void GenerateMesh()
    {
        meshf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        mesh = new UnityEngine.Mesh();
        meshf.mesh = mesh;
        mesh.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add a collider to a mesh. You had a collider to a gameobject with a mesh attached to it

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this to `GameObject`. Like for instance in your `Start` method `BoxCollider`:

```
private void Start()
{
    GenerateMesh();
    BoxCollider boxCollider = this.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah there is a problem if i add a BoxCollider then i can't assign the SharedMesh property with the Mesh: gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        transform.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh; But if i add Meshcollider instead boxCollider i need to change all the time the convex property of the MeshCollider.